# Does sign-magnitude ordering admit infinite descending chains in any discretely ordered ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, order-theory, well-orders

I have a conjecture:

Let $R$ be an ordered ring $(S, 0, 1, +, ·, <)$.

Let $|x| = x$ if $0 \leq x$ and $|x| = -x$ if $x < 0$.

Define $x \preccurlyeq y$ to hold if either $|x| < |y|$ or both $|x| = |y|$ and $y < x$. Observe that $\preccurlyeq$ is an ordering, though not congruent with $+$ or $·$.

Assume $1$ is the smallest positive number.

Then $\preccurlyeq$ admits of no infinite descending chains.

Is this conjecture true?

Note: if $0 < q < 1$ then $0 = 0q < qq < 1q = q$ i.e. $0 < q^2 < q$, and all $q^{2^n}$ are distinct by transitivity and irreflexivity, and form an infinite descending chain. So I need 1 to be the smallest positive number.

But then if $n < q < n+1$ where $n = 1 + \ldots + 1$, then $0 < q - n < 1$ which we assumed to not be true. If $k < q < k+1 \leq 0$ then $-0 = 0 \leq -(k+1) < -q < -k$. So there cannot be any numbers "between the integers". Can there be numbers "beyond the integers"?

Otherwise, for any $x$ I think I can let $m$ be the smallest $1 + \ldots + 1$ such that $|x| \leq m$, and then there are only finitely many non-negative values smaller than $m$, and thus only finitely many values $\preccurlyeq$-smaller than $x$, and my conjecture holds.

I observe with curiosity that one can prove the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) for the reals using the least upper bound property. I'm not sure what to make of that, but it smells relevant.

Comment: The use of the ordering $\preceq$ is not really relevant; you might as well just restrict to positive elements and use just the ordinary order.

Comment: I suspected this was true; however, I wasn't fully certain, so I would rather state exactly the problem I'm interested in (or at least the mathematical parts of it), rather than a maybe-perfect proxy. The particular problem is showing termination of ScalaCheck shrinkers on integral types in general, using a minimal set of assumptions. I want to use the ⪯ ordering for its ergonomic factors: people think more easily about positive numbers than negative numbers, and I output the most ⪯-minimal datum I can get my hands on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an explicit counterexample, consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ ordered such that $t$ is infinitely large.  Explicitly, a polynomial is positive with respect to this order iff its leading coefficient is positive.  The smallest positive element is $1$, but $t,t-1,t-2,\dots$ is an infinite descending chain of positive elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you know a little bit of model theory, then a counterexample to your hypothesis can be constructed via the [compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem) and the fact that the theory of ordered rings is first-order. Let $\mathcal{L}=\{0,1,+,\cdot,<\}$ be the language of ordered rings, and define a new language $\mathcal{L}'=\mathcal{L}\cup\{c\}$ with a single new constant symbol $c$. Now, let $T$ be the $\mathcal{L}$-theory of ordered rings, and define a new $\mathcal{L}'$-theory $T'$ to be the union of

1. The $\mathcal{L}$-theory $T$.
2. The axiom $\forall v\left[(v\geqslant 1)\vee (v\leqslant 0)\right]$.
3. Axioms $c>\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{n\text{ times}}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Any finite subset of $T'$ is satisfiable in $\mathbb{Z}$ by taking $c$ to be sufficiently large, and so, by the compactness theorem, $T'$ has a model $R$. Then $R$ is a model of $T$ and hence an ordered ring and, by the second axiom above, has $1$ as its smallest positive element. However, denoting by $r$ the realization of $c$ in $R$, the sequence $$r>r-1>r-(1+1)>r-(1+1+1)>\dots$$ is an infinite descending chain of positive elements, and hence a infinite descending chain under $\succ$, thus giving the desired counterexample.